# Unexpected results when converting while loop to for loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a while loop that generally works well but I would like to convert it to a for loop. The while loop is as follows:

```
with open(filename) as a:
while tally != c:
    line = a.readline()
    c = line.strip()
```

Where I open a file, read each line until I find the line I am interested in. The for loop is as follows:

```
with open(filename) as a:
for line in enumerate (a):
    if tally == c:
        break
    elif tally != c:
        c = line
```

It appears that the loop just reads to the end of the file every time and turns the variable `c` into a tuple consisting of a random number and the last line of the file. I know the string contained in `tally` exists in the file because the while loop performs the intended function.

Comment: `c = line` is different from `c = line.strip()`.

Comment: Also, `for line in a`, not `for line in enumerate(a)`.

Comment: I assume the indentation issues in the code in the question are just errors introduced in copy/paste.

Comment: Definitely a copy/paste issue on the indentation. That would have been a colossal embarrassment if that were the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
with open(filename) as a:
    for line in a:
        if tally == c:
            break
        else:
            c = line.strip()
```

Two issues:

1. `for line in enumerate(a)` means `line` gets a tuple on each iteration of the line number and the actual line from the file. Read up on `enumerate` to understand its use.
2. `c = line` is different from `c = line.strip()` in your original loop.

Comment: Now the file that I pulled 'enumerate' from makes more sense as well, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `c=line` it must be `c=line.strip()`.

Comment: Sorry! As answered by smarx line.strip() had to be used.I have edited my answer.